# Equating string arrays of two text files

Tags: c#, text

I have two text files.

First text file (Test1.txt) has a content like below:

```
T1
T2 
T3
S1
S2 
S3
```

Second text file (Test2.txt) has a content like below:

```
T2,James
T3,Cindy
S2,John
S3,Martha
```

Desired Output (Test3.txt) is below:

```
T1
James
Cindy
S1
John
Martha
```

I've tried below code but it seems that the second text file is not being considered. Need your help guys in correcting my code. Thank you very much in advanced.

```
string line;
string DatabaseFullPath = @"D:\Test1.txt";
string line2;
string DatabaseFullPath2 = @"D:\Test2.txt";

//write to new text file
using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test3.txt"))

//read second text file
using (var file2 = new StreamReader(DatabaseFullPath2))
{
   line2 = file2.ReadLine();
   var ProjectInfo2 = line2.Split(',');

   //read first text file
   using (var file = new StreamReader(DatabaseFullPath))
   {
      //loop on all lines of first text file
      while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         //compare lines with all the first column of second text file
         if (line == ProjectInfo2[0])
         {
            //put ProjectInfo2[1] on label 1. label 1 as a container
            label1.Text = ProjectInfo2[1];
         }
         else
         {
            //put line on label 1. label 1 as a container
            label1.Text = line.Trim();
         }

         //write all values of label1.Text
         writetext.WriteLine(label1.Text.Trim());
     }
  }
}
```

Current Output:

```
T1
T2 
T3
S1
S2
S3
```

Comment: You should compare strings using equals not ==, but what is your current output?

Comment: @Killer Death: it seems that `Test1.txt` contains trailing spaces; I've added `Trim()`s to the code to solve such problem (see my edit)

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Code is working. Thank you very much. I will learn more about dictionary. GOD bless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using *dictionary* in order to build collection of the key/value pairs:

```
   { "T2", "James"}
   { "T3", "Cindy"}
   { "S2", "John"}
   { "S3", "Martha"}
```

you can implement it in this way:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

...

Dictionary<string, string> CodeToName = File
  .ReadLines("Test2.txt")
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .GroupBy(items => items[0].Trim())
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, 
                chunk => string.Join("; ", chunk.Select(item => item[1].Trim())));
```

Having a dictionary you can easily find out corresponding values:

```
string name = null;

File.WriteAllLines("Test3.txt", File
  .ReadLines("Test1.txt")
  .Select(line => CodeToName.TryGetValue(line.Trim(), out name) 
     ? name 
     : line));
```

In case of C# 7.0+ you can simplify the later into

```
File.WriteAllLines("Test3.txt", File
  .ReadLines("Test1.txt")
  .Select(line => CodeToName.TryGetValue(line.Trim(), out var name) // out var syntax
     ? name 
     : line));
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thank you very much for the reply. I have used the code but I've got the same result as the current output. T1,T2,T3,S1,S2,S3

Answer (score 0):

In case of small files you can use this approach:

```
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Test1.txt");
var file2 = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Test2.txt");

var result = file1.Select(l1 => 
    file2.FirstOrDefault(l2 => l2.StartsWith($"{l1},"))?.Substring(l1.Length + 1) ?? l1);
File.WriteAllLines(@"D:\Test3.txt", result);
```

Comment: Hi Aleks. Thank you very much for the reply. I tried the code but I am getting unexpected character '$'.

Comment: @ThomasArriola it's a string interpolation, a c# 6 feature. You can replace `$"{l1},"` with `l1 + ","`